# Are there any statically typed languages with generators?

Tags: python, static, generator

I've been using Python a great deal recently and have been wondering if there are any modern statically typed languages with syntactic support for generators like

```
def gen():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i << 100

for big_num in gen():
    print(big_num)
```

I thought Scala had them, but it seems this isn't the case.

Comment: This question is indeed off-topic, but I would suggest taking a look at `C#`.

Comment: Look at Scala's `Stream` class - it has methods which generate a lazy sequence

Comment: Scala does indeed have features that are very similar to generators. For example `for(i <- 1 to 10) yield(i)` or you could use an Iterator. `Iterator.iterate(0)(_ + 1).take(10)`

Comment: @Daenyth I already told the Haskell guy, generators are not just about laziness but also about suspension (they're a limited form of coroutines) and syntax.

Comment: Google results seem to suggest it's possible to implement coroutines in a library in scala.

Comment: @Daenyth With nice syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haskell has [conduits](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/conduit-overview) which are somewhat more general, but certainly able to achieve a behaviour very similar to Python's generators:

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Bits
import Data.Conduit
import qualified Data.Conduit.List as CL

gen :: (Monad m) => Source m Integer
gen = forM_ [0..9] $ \i -> 
          yield (i `shiftL` 100)

main = gen $$ CL.mapM_ print
```

Comment: Not quite the same. After you evaluate `take 10 gen`, the first 10 elements of `gen` will remain in memory for the life time of `gen`, whereas a generator would store nothing in memory.

Comment: @sepp2k Well only if it doesn't get optimized away, which I doubt in this case for any decent compiler

Comment: Generators are not just about laziness, but also about a convenient way to express ordinary code with suspension points sprinkled in. "Iterable" is a closer Python concept, the moral equivalent of your `gen` would be `map(lambda n: n << 100, range(0, 10))`.

Comment: @delnan Ok then, Source m Integer is probably a better analogon

Comment: @NiklasB. Semantically, it stays. To be optimized away, the code has to be written to only use it once (and that in a way the compiler understands, but that's another problem).

Comment: @delnan Added a conduit example that does not build up the prefix in memory